# CATransform3DRotate effects gone after applying anchor point

Tags: ios, catransform3d, catransform3drotate

EDIT with correct observation.

I used the following two snippets to rotate an UIImageView.  After the stage1, I got the desired 3D effect: the view rotate (3D effect) and stretched out (larger size).  On stage2, I am trying to swing the rightView with the hinge on the right.

If I applied the line that changes the anchor point, the view swings correctly (hinge on right) with one major issue: The view's size got restored back to original size (smaller) while the (rotation) 3D effect is still intact and then the swinging occurs.

Any suggestions?

```
rightView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5); 


-(void)stage1
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5  animations:^{
        rightView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0);   //rightView i UIImageView
        CATransform3D _3Dt = CATransform3DIdentity;
        _3Dt =CATransform3DMakeRotation(3.141f/42.0f,0.0f,-1.0f,0.0f);  
        _3Dt.m34 = -0.001f;
        _3Dt.m14 = -0.0015f;
        rightView.layer.transform = _3Dt;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        if (finished) {
            NSLog(@"finished..");
        }
    }];
}

-(void)Stage2
{
    rightView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);   //issue?
    rightView.center = CGPointMake(1012, 384);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.75 animations:^{
        CATransform3D rightTransform = rightView.layer.transform;
        rightTransform.m34 = 1.0f/500; 
        rightTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rightTransform, M_PI_2, 0, 1, 0);
        rightView.layer.transform = rightTransform;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}
```

Comment: Changing the anchorpoint also changes the way the transform is applied. Can you please generate a image of the wanted results in e.g. Photoshop? Initial state, state when stage1 animation is done, state when stage2 animation is done?

Comment: @hfossli, pictures added.  I also added a picture right before stage2 animation occurs.  Note, I can use setFrame to change to frame of rightView before the stage2 animation, but I can't get it to match the original 3D effect (angle, etc) after stage1 animation.

Comment: Is the images you've uploaded the desired output or the "wrong" output?

Comment: @hfossli, It was the wrong.  Picture 4 was the result of the animated picture 3 not picture 2.  Picture 3, As you can see the anchorPoint setting changed the size of picture 2.

Comment: What happens if you leave out     rightView.center = CGPointMake(1012, 384); ?  Or put it with in the animation?  I think that would make the view jump before the 2nd animation begins.

Comment: For debugging purposes, leave out the part about angles. Does the size still change? Another question is are you sure that stage2 code is not initiated before stage1 is done?

Comment: @hfossli, not sure what you meant by leave angles out?  Yes, stage1 occurs before stage2.  Also, if i remove the anchorpoint setting line (and the center moving line), picture2 will keep it current size and 3d perspective.  But it will swing with the hinge on left.

Comment: @HalR, left the center line out would not make any difference.  The anchor setting lie is the cause of the reducing of the view.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the "options" to your animate with duration and add `options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState`

Otherwise it starts from the beginning again.

So your stage 2 would look like this:

```
-(void)Stage2
{
    rightView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);   //issue?
    rightView.center = CGPointMake(1012, 384);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.75
                          delay:0.00 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
        CATransform3D rightTransform = rightView.layer.transform;
        rightTransform.m34 = 1.0f/500; 
        rightTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rightTransform, M_PI_2, 0, 1, 0);
        rightView.layer.transform = rightTransform;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}
```

Comment: I tried but it produced the same result.  Just as my original snippet, if I did not set the anchorPoint, then the original transformation effect is intact.  The anchorPoint seems to be the culprit.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: My original observation was wrong.  Please see the update if you are still interested.  Thanks.

Comment: In my case, its a layer. Any property to set CABasicAnimation to start from the current state of the layer?