# How to take the screenshot( or image merge) for the 3D Transformed image?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimageview, screenshot

I want to merge the two images(Check screenshot 1), and change to the single image. But I am mot able to merge the 3D Transformed image.

If I merge the image means, its goes to the original size(Check screenshot 2).

How can I **merge the image** or **take screenshot** for the 3D Transformed image view.

[image] [image]

I am used following code for merge the images,

```
-(UIImage *)captureView:(UIImageView *)imageView
{
    //Merge the two images.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backgroundImageView.frame.size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [imageView.layer renderInContext:ctx];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1949003/2407907)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take screen shot of 3D transformed view, you need to convert 3D transformed view to affine transform and then take the screen shot

Comment: @ Maddy Oven, Can you give the procedure or source code for 3D Transform to Affine transform. Affine transform used for the 2D transform.

Comment: @Mani, There is a method "CATransform3DGetAffineTransform" of quartz core framework which takes 3D transform as input and returns you the equivalent  affine transform.

Comment: @ Maddy Oven, You are great...! This method "CATransform3DGetAffineTransform" working nice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ Maddy Oven, rsImageView.layer.affineTransform   = CATransform3DGetAffineTransform(rsImageView.layer.transform);           
But I got some changes on the image. This conversion change the original transformed image. Can you let me know, the reason of the issue.

Comment: @Mani: Can you provide more details on what is changed on the image?